# Map with more than 1 million markers, issue at high zoom level

Tags: google-maps, hierarchical-clustering

**Context:**

Google Map with 1 million markers (object with a lat/long) to display. We use Fluster 2 for clustering.

For zoom level 11 to 21 (assuming there are 21 zoom levels and 21 is the closest to the ground) the computation time for clustering markers (create cluster markers) is fine.

**Issue I encounter:**

Agglomeration clustering is being slow down after zoom 11 (when the user zooms out from the ground). Given the number of markers, around 1,000,000, I need either a fast computation method or a turnaround.

Btw, I am not interested in commercial solutions.

Comment: [Please read this concerning ALL CAPS TITLES](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/11043)

Answer (score 1):

Fluster 2 is a javascript which is client side clustering right?

With millions of points you should consider definitely use server side clustering or even pre-cluster points in advance if possible.

This topic is related to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986852/clustering-coordinates-on-server-side

With that many points you could make a simple grid-clustering.
This is fast technique as mentioned by google
http://code.google.com/intl/da-K/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html#gridbasedclustering

I have made a blog about grid-clustering with example code in C#
http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/clustering-grid-cluster.

Interesting question :)
In an algorithm design book by jon kleinberg there is mention of calculation of 1.000.000 items gives about 1 sec for O(n) and 20 sec for O(nlogn).

Some tricks should be considered to only use partial of the data in the calculation if you can't keep it O(n).

Comment: Interesting but is there a reason for a quadtree or a grid when you can use a r-tree? My answer was about a curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spatial index and reduce the dimension. Then you can pull markers separately on each zoom levels. I wrote a PHP script with many space filling curve and a quadkey for academic purpose. I've also some commercial solution.

To start you can read:

- http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

When you need a more accurate search you can still use it to eliminate nearest-neighbor computation with all locations.